# Elasticsearch java api for full text search with filters

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-java-api

I want to do a full text search on string "user" which can match any feild in my document and then apply filter so that i get only records where the value of x feild is either "abc" or "xyz".

Fiddling with Sense , the below request fulfills my requirement.

```
GET _search
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
             "query_string": {
                 "query": "user"
         }
         },
         "filter":
             [

                    {"term": { "x": "abc"}},
                     {"term": { "x": "xyz"}}              
            ]    
      }
   }
}
```

But, i want a java api to do the above stuff. I have searched the elastic documentation and the SO , but have not found what i am looking for as api like QueryBuilders.filteredQuery seems deprecated . I am currently using 2.3.4 but can upgrade.

Comment: Check it : https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch 2.x java Api doesn't have implementation for filtered query. According to the elasticsearch documentation, they suggest to [use the bool query instead with a must clause for the query and a filter clause for the filter.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)

In java you could create a method to create a wrapper method for the filtered query. This would be like:

```
   public static QueryBuilder filteredQuery(QueryBuilder query, QueryBuilder filter){
        BoolQueryBuilder filteredQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(query);
        return filteredQuery.filter(filter);

    }
```

where,

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("user");
QueryBuilder filter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("x", "abc", "xyz")));
```

This query is equivalent to the one mentioned above. Hope this helps